# Python error using Faceit plugin in Blender 3.1.2

Tags: python, rigging, add-on

I know next to nothing about Python and I've ran into this error when generating the rig section  of the Faceit plugin. [Here's a video reference for what I'm talking about](https://youtu.be/KEx64_1Zd3g?t=104). Can anyone tell me what this means? Is it fixable or will I have to go back a few steps in my rigging process?

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\faceit\rig_operators.py", line 30, in invoke
    return self.execute(context)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\faceit\rig_operators.py", line 37, in execute
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.vertex_size = scene.faceit_vertex_size
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: ThemeView3D.vertex_size expected an int type, not float

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I have the body rigged and the head geo is attached to the appropriate bone of that rig and now I'm trying to add shapekeys to the face geo. Apologies if this isn't enough description, I can go into more detail if required.

Comment: That is a bug in the addon. Looks like it might be caused by a change in the Blender Python API. You might be able to fix it yourself by just going to that file on your hard drive, line 37 like it says, and changing this line: `bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.vertex_size = scene.faceit_vertex_size` to `bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.vertex_size = int(scene.faceit_vertex_size)`. but I would still report it to the developer if possible.

Comment: do you have the solution? same problem